# Failed To Transfer BEP20 Smart Contract Token

Tags: node.js, web3js

I am writing an API to transfer my custom bep20 contract token from the owner's account to another account. For example, I have 10,000 units of my token in my wallet and i want to transfer any specified amount to another account using web3js inside the node server. here is what I have done so far and is not working properly. am having `Failed` as the response and also `Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:`

Here is my token transferring function in node:

```
async transferToken(pkey, tokenContractAddress , toAddress , amount , chainId, callback) {
        //import account by private key
        let account = this.web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(pkey);
        let wallet = this.web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);
        // ABI to transfer ERC20 Token
        let abi = ABI_CONFIG;
        // calculate ERC20 token amount
        let tokenAmount = this.web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether')
        // Get ERC20 Token contract instance
        let contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(abi, tokenContractAddress, {from: wallet.address});
        const data = await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, tokenAmount).encodeABI();
        // The gas price is determined by the last few blocks median gas price.
        const gasPrice = await this.web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const gasLimit = 90000;
        // Build a new transaction object.
        const rawTransaction = {
            'from': wallet.address,
            'nonce': this.web3.utils.toHex(this.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet.address)),
            'gasPrice': this.web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
            'gasLimit': this.web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
            'to': tokenContractAddress,
            'value': 0,
            'data': data,
            'chainId': chainId
        };
        const res = await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, tokenAmount).send({
            from: wallet.address,
            gas: 30400
        });
        console.log(res);
        // Get Name
        let name = await contract.methods.name().call();
        // Get Symbol
        let symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();

        /* send to hyperledger */
        const map = {
            "action_type" : "SEND_TOKEN",
            "from_wallet_address" : wallet.address,
            "to_wallet_address" : toAddress,
            "amount" : this.web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether'),
            "tx_hash" : res.transactionHash,
            "gasLimit" : 21000,
            "gasPrice" : gasPrice,
            "fee" : gasPrice * 21000,
            "token_smart_contract" : tokenContractAddress,
            "token_name" : name,
            "token_symbol" : symbol,
            "status" : "SUCCESS"
        }

        callback({data: res, map});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough gas to complete the operation as most of the 30400 was used by the transaction. I think you must increase your gas limit from 30400 to 100000 for example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).